# Faraday Connection: Switching the request mode?

Tags: ruby, faraday

I am using `faraday` to handle some requests to an internal API. The API endpoints use a CSRF token, so I am also using `faraday-cookie_jar`.

For a couple of the API endpoints, they require a `:multipart` request. Others do not.

### Question

Is there any way to utilize the same `Connection` object, but switch whether or not you are doing a `:multipart` or a `:url_encoded` request?

Currently, I have to use two connections depending on which type of request I'm making. It does not seem you can change a connection's request method after it has done at least 1 request.

```rb
@connection = Faraday.new(url: 'http://localhost:3000') do |faraday|
  faraday.request :url_encoded
  faraday.use :cookie_jar
  faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end

@connection.get '/something'

# try to change to :multipart
@connection.request :multipart # => Faraday::RackBuilder::StackLocked: can't modify middleware stack after making a request
```

It doesn't seem to allow you to switch after you've made a request. I know that you can modify the request a bit for each request itself by passing a block, but I can't seem to find where to modify to switch to `:multipart` in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to include *both* middleware options when creating your connection (`:url_encoded` and `:multipart`), and then switch using explicit `Content-Type` headers.

Per the [Faraday ReadMe](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday#advanced-middleware-usage), you can specify 'em both.  An excerpt:

> ```
>  Faraday.new(...) do |conn|
>     # POST/PUT params encoders:
>     conn.request :multipart
>     conn.request :url_encoded
>     conn.adapter :net_http
>   end
> ```
>
> This request middleware setup affects POST/PUT requests in the following way:
>
> 1. `Request::Multipart` checks for files in the payload, otherwise leaves everything untouched;
> 2. `Request::UrlEncoded` encodes as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" if not already encoded or of another type.

So adding `:multipart` still allows for url-encoded posts, because it only matters when there are files in the payload.  Then, if you explicitly set your `Content-Type` for the file upload, you should be fine - Faraday will use the correct request middleware because you explicitly told it to use multipart.  But if you *don't* specify, it will default to url-encoded.

```
# works using :url_encoded
@connection.post '/something' do |req|
  req.body = { some: 'posted fields' }
end

# works using :multipart because Content-Type was explicitly set
@connection.post '/some_file_endpoint' do |req|
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data'
  req.body = { file_field: Faraday::UploadIO.new(file_path, 'text/plain') }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `@connection.request :multipart` adds `Faraday::Request::Multipart` to `@connecton.builder.handlers`. If you want to remove something, you can manipulate that array.

I make no claim that messing with Faraday's (relative) internals is a good idea. Keeping your two connections sounds like a better plan.

Answer (score 0):

Sean’s answer sounds like the right thing to do here, but if you *do* want to modify your connection, you have to duplicate it before:

```rb
@connection = @connection.dup
@connection.request :multipart
```

This can also be used to delete middleware from a connection:

```rb
@connection = @connection.dup
@connection.builder.delete(Faraday::Request::lookup_middleware(:multipart))
```